# Update elasticsearch Document using Spark

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, elasticsearch-5

I am using following command to persist data in elastic search using spark streaming.

val ES_CONFIGURATION = Map(ConfigurationOptions.ES_NODES ->"192.168.1.1", ConfigurationOptions.ES_PORT -> "9200")

val ES_CONFIG = ES_CONFIGURATION + (ConfigurationOptions.ES_MAPPING_ID -> "key") + (ConfigurationOptions.ES_HTTP_TIMEOUT -> "3s")

```
  EsSparkSQL.saveToEs(DataFrame, indexname, ES_CONFIG)
```

With this, I am overwriting entire document, which I don't want.

I want to update only the fields for which data exists in this dataframe.

Please suggest, How to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

Use `es.mapping.id`

to specify which document it will update:

`EsSparkSQL.saveToEs(df, indexname, Map("es.mapping.id" -> "mappingColumn"))`

Comment: That i am doing... Problem is not there... For the perticular Mapping ID, I do not want to update all the fields in this document.. Only want to update the fields that are part of the dataframe... Rest of the fields should remain as they were before...

Comment: hi, the behaviour should be upsert by default; https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html

Comment: No... It is overWritting the entire document... Can you please suggest if I can use any other function or any parameter change is required?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following config "es.write.operation" as "upsert".
By default the mode is "index" for which new data is added while existing data (based on its id) is replaced (reindexed).
When if you specify "es.mapping.id" it will still continue to override the document.

Please refer the official documentation
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html

Hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "append" while saving the document.

EsSparkSQL.write.format().options().mode("append").save(imdex)

Answer (score 0):

may be you can exclude the fields you don't want to be updated

```
es_conf = {
   "es.mapping.id": "id",                      
   "es.mapping.exclude": "my_unwanted_field",               
   "es.write.operation": "update"               
}
```